# What is the MVC equivalent of Find Control?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms

In ASP.NET web forms it is possible to modify page controls from the master page.  For example, on a page "/Sample" I could set TextBox1 as readonly by doing the following.

```
//Site.master.cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Path.ToUpper().Contains("/SAMPLE"))
    {
        TextBox TB = MainContent.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
        TB.ReadOnly = true;
    }
}
```

The question is... **Is there an equivalent way to do this in an MVC application that uses a SiteLayout?**

> Background: We have purchased an MVC application and have access to modify the
>   source code.  We need to customize the behaviors on some of the pages.  It
>   will only be used by a few dozen people so a performance hit won't really be noticeable.  If this was a Web Forms
>   application we would use the above method.  *However* this application
>   is written with MVC and it is making our web form programmer (me) confused on how best to proceed.  Customizing numerous pages is going to be a headache when
>   we have to patch the software.  Having all the changes in one central location
>   would be easier to manage going forward.  How can you have one place where you can customize other pages programmatically in MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no MVC equivalent for `FindControl`, since views are built in a single operation, where ASP.NET controls are built up and modified over several different events. You don't need to find the control, you specify all of its attributes as it is built.

The rough equivalent to an ASP.NET control (at least in this context) is an [HTML helper](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs). HTML helpers are implemented as static extension methods, which allows them to be shared between views and perform some actions as the view is loaded.

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString TextBox1(this HtmlHelper helper, string name)
    {
        if (helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Path.ToUpper().Contains("/SAMPLE"))
        {
            return InputExtensions.TextBox(helper, name, null, new { @readonly = "readonly" });
        }

        return InputExtensions.TextBox(helper, name);
    }
}
```

## Usage

**~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p class="site-title">@Html.ActionLink("your logo here", "Index", "Home")</p>
                </div>
                <div class="float-right">
                    <section id="login">
                        @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                    </section>
                    <nav>
                        <ul id="menu">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="body">
            @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">

                @* Render custom HTML Helper *@
                @Html.TextBox1("test")

                @RenderBody()
            </section>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET MVC Application</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that it is also possible to put the logic directly in the view, but then you cannot reuse logic in other views and it makes your view look cluttered.

As for reading the data back out of a textbox, you need to put it within a `<form>` tag so it can be posted to a controller action method, which is the rough equivalent of a submit button click event. Unlike ASP.NET, MVC supports multiple `<form>` tags so you don't have to mix your logic for different actions on the page.

Comment: Is there no way of adding a function at render saying "If Page = X then set Textbox1 to ReadOnly"?

Comment: You could use [sections](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor) to do it that way. You just need to override the section on each applicable view (when page = X). But the example you gave was to disable the textbox when the URL contains `/sample`, so that is the answer I provided.

Comment: that comment was meant for a different post.  I deleted it right away.  You are too good and should never have noticed it!

Comment: Is there a way to extend HTMLExtenders?  For example, add another step to the TextBoxFor method?

Comment: There is no way to extend them, but since they are extension methods you can add your own overloads so they work seamlessly and look just like the existing ones. You can create extension methods with your own names to indicate custom logic. You can even create [templated HTML helpers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee308450(v=vs.100).aspx) that allow you to customize the HTML in a view template instead of creating an HTML helper for every scenario. You just need to import the custom HTML helper namespace  in the `/Views/web.config` file so they are visible within your views.

Comment: If I could overwrite some helpers like TextBoxFor then I might be able to do what I want to.  However it seems like the simplest course of action is just to make the changes to the code itself and document each change.  Marked your answer as the correct one.

Comment: No problem. Note that when in doubt about anything MVC related, you can always [analyze the source](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Web.Mvc/Html/HtmlHelperExtensions.cs). MVC is open source unlike ASP.NET (well, ASP.NET prior to 5 anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad. But generally, if you want to provide read only rendering for your controls in your razor views based on some conditions, you can try the below approach.

You should add a `IsReadOnly` property to your view model and use that to render the control the way you wanted.

```
public class CreateCustomerVM
{
    public bool IsReadOnly {set;get;} 

    //Other properties goes here
    public string Email { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }

}
```

In your Action method set the `IsReadOnly` propery value based on your condition.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var vm=new CreateCustomerVM();

  //Set the value based on your condition
  vm.IsReadOnly=true;

  return View(vm);    
}
```

And in your view , you use the `IsReadOnly` property to determine whether you want to display a readonly control or not.

```
@model YourNameSpaceGoesHere.CreateCustomerVM
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)

    if(Model.IsReadOnly)
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
    }
    <input type="submit"/>
}
```

Comment: Yes, this does not answer the question as I intended it to be asked.  This may be my fault in not explaining it well enough.  I would like 1 central location where I can override control behavior in MVC.  I understand MVC is different and the idea of "controls" is a bit more consistent with Web Forms.  However, I need one location where I can override textbox/checkbox/button/etc... properties.  I understand this may be an odd request but keep in mind that we need an easy to manage way of managing changes when the commercial MVC application gets upgraded/patched.